# Select Rows On PrimeNG Table With Keypress

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am working with a PrimeNG table, and am trying to select the row of a `pSelectableRow` by keypress.

I have a global search input that will filter all results of the table, and when the user is done searching, I would like them to be able to click a button on the keyboard and have the row selected from the filtered options.

Currently, if a user is searching and the input box has the focus, they can press `tab` , but they must press 5 times in order to get down to to first row (more if there are more columns).

Is it possible to select a row element within the app component via typescript or other method where on a keypress, the first row would be selected? Then of course, the user could press `enter` to actually select the row. The up and down arrows work once the rows are active, but you need to get to the rows first.

I have set up a hotkey function inside of my app so that the `f1` key triggers an event:

```
this.addShortcut({ keys: 'f1' }).subscribe(() => {
  this.showMessage();
  console.log(this.table.value);
});
```

This is showing a message from the PrimeNG message service to make sure the hotkey is working, and it is also logging the value of the table to the console. I have looked through the `table` and there doesn't seem to be any way of selecting a row. I have tried setting the `this.table.selection = this.table.value[1]` and this does store the `[1]` array item as the "selected value", but this does not actually select any item from the table.

Is there a better way of doing this?
For simplicity of the code required to make this reproducible in StackOverflow, I have included a stackblitz instead.
Here is a [stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledynamic-demo-u6qkam?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `[(selection)]="selectedProduct" (onFilter)="onFilter($event, dt)"` to your table declaration in your component, then you can manage your table selection every time the user makes a search this way:

```
onFilter(event, dt) {
    if (event.filteredValue.length > 0) {
      this.selectedProduct = event.filteredValue[0]; // set first visible row as selected
    }
  }
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledynamic-demo-amkn8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Is that what you are looking for?

**Edit:**

Ok, I hope I've understood your need. I added three `HostListener` to navigate along the filtered data and execute an action while pressing *Enter* key:

```
  @HostListener('keydown.ArrowUp', ['$event']) ArrowUp($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.cpt > 0) {
      this.cpt--;
    }
    this.selectedProduct = this.visibleProducts[this.cpt];
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.ArrowDown', ['$event']) ArrowDown(
    $event: KeyboardEvent
  ) {
    if (this.cpt < this.visibleProducts.length - 1) {
      this.cpt++;
    }
    this.selectedProduct = this.visibleProducts[this.cpt];
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.Enter', ['$event']) Enter($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    alert('opening product: ' + this.selectedProduct.name);
  }
```

And now, the `onFilter` method looks like:

```
  onFilter(event, dt) {
    this.cpt = 0;
    if (event.filteredValue.length > 0) {
      this.selectedProduct = event.filteredValue[0];
      this.visibleProducts = event.filteredValue;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The look of this is similar, but the functionality is not quite. What the user would need to do is select a row with the `enter` key. In the example here, the row is "selected", but when enter is pressed, it does not trigger the `(onRowSelect)` . Ideally, the user should type something in the search box and then can arrow up/down into the table to "select" (highlight) a row, then click `enter` to actually select it. For example, this here: https://imgur.com/okwUfZK  shows a selected row where the user can now click `enter` . They would ideally need to go up and down between row items as well

Comment: Please check updated Stackblitz and tell me if it's ok or not.

Comment: This looks good. After your first reply I thought that may be a good way to implement it. I really like what you've done, thanks for your help